Can primer paint be used as the final coat?
A new set of white fiberglass doors has been installed and a coat of white primer has been applied.   Is there any reason not to use primer as the final coat?

LOL no, it'll mar easily, show scrapes and be hard to clean.  It's designed to present a semi-porous and rough surface for a finish coat to stick to.

Yes, primer is not designed to behave as the final coat, it is designed to fill tiny holes in some cases and provide a secure base for the top coat or coats.
Do follow the instructions for the paint system provided by the paint manufacturer as performance is dependant on the correct surface preparation and application.
